# SonarQube isn't starting and no error seems to show up in the console output. Could someone help me figure what's wrong?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to start SonarQube on a Windows 10 box. I've installed Postgres 10. When I run StartSonar.bat, I get the following:

> wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
>   wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
>   jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
>   jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
>   jvm 1    |
>   jvm 1    | 2019.02.07 06:22:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\sonarqube-7.5\sonarqube-7.5\temp
>   jvm 1    | 2019.02.07 06:22:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
>   jvm 1    | 2019.02.07 06:22:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\sonarqube-7.5\sonarqube-7.5\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\sonarqube-7.5\sonarqube-7.5\elasticsearch -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -Epath.conf=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\sonarqube-7.5\sonarqube-7.5\temp\conf\es
>   jvm 1    | 2019.02.07 06:22:23 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
>   jvm 1    | 2019.02.07 06:22:23 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
>   jvm 1    | 2019.02.07 06:22:23 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
>   jvm 1    | 2019.02.07 06:22:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
>   jvm 1    | 2019.02.07 06:22:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\sonarqube-7.5\sonarqube-7.5]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\sonarqube-7.5\sonarqube-7.5\temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*;C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\sonarqube-7.5\sonarqube-7.5\lib\jdbc\postgresql\postgresql-42.2.5.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\sonarqube-7.5\sonarqube-7.5\temp\sq-process8601102404220274862properties
>   jvm 1    | 2019.02.07 06:22:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
>   jvm 1    | 2019.02.07 06:22:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
>   jvm 1    | 2019.02.07 06:22:36 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
>   wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped

The following are the changes I've made to the sonar.properties file:

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonarqube

# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
sonar.web.host=192.0.0.1


# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Default value is 9000.
sonar.web.port=9000

# Defaults are respectively <installation home>/data and <installation home>/temp
sonar.path.data=data
sonar.path.temp=temp
```

The following are screenshots from pgAdmin:

[image: Server Connection settings]
[image: Browser pane]

Comment: Have a look at the logs under the {sonarqube}\logs directory - there should be more info in them about what is failing. There are separate log files for different components: es.log = elasticsearch, ce.log=compute engine, web.log = UI, sonar.log = general. Look at sonar.log first.

Comment: @duncanp Thanks for the tip. I managed to solve the issue thanks to this

Answer (score 0):

So there were two issues.

The first was due to the **sonar.web.host** property. I had set it to **192.0.0.1** and after I changed it to **127.0.0.1**, this issue was resolved.

The second issue was due to the port the database server was using. After I changed it to the default (i.e. **5432**), it worked.